# How do I use a CSV to supply data for a vbar using Bokeh?

Tags: python, csv, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh glyphs with data from a CSV file (or multiple files). I know we can import CSV's using the CSV reader but how do I then get Bokeh to use it for the glyphs?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()
colours = ["red","blue","green","purple","yellow","orange"]
import csv

with open("HomelessInIrelandNov18.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if any (row[key] for key in row):
            print(row["REGION"], row["HOMELESS ADULTS"]
                  p=figure(x_range=ratings_categories,title="Homeless In Ireland 2018", plot_height=200)
                  p.vbar(x=row["REGION"], top = row["HOMELESS ADULTS"],width=0.9, color=colours)
show(p)
```

Comment: Hi, it would be much easier to help point at a concrete solution if you include the actual data you are trying to load. Otherwise, all I an say is that generally speaking you would not want/need to call `figure` and `vbar` multiple times in a loop. Instead, you should collect your data into lists/arrays and use those functions once, at the end.

Comment: Thank you bigreddot!                import csv

with open("HomelessInIrelandNov18.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',')
    adults = []
    region = []
    
    for row in reader:
        region.append(row["REGION"])
        adults.append(row["HOMELESS ADULTS"])

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()
colours = ["red","blue","green","purple","yellow","orange"]
                  
p=figure(x_range=region,title="Homeless In Ireland 2018", plot_height=200)
p.vbar(x=region, top = adults,width=0.9, color=colours)
show(p)

Comment: Right, I mean that you are the only one who has the file. I am asking you to make it available so that others can help you more directly. Right now we can only guess at the contents, so we can only speculate about as answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the [dataset](https://www.housing.gov.ie/sites/default/files/publications/files/homeless_report_-_november_2018_0.pdf) you're using after some Googling. I loaded the csv file with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), this is a really nice tool to load and edit CSV/Excel files. I removed all the loops and instead called the figure/vbar function once and loaded the data in as Pandas series.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import viridis

output_notebook()
df = pd.read_csv('HomelessInIrelandNov18.csv')
colours = viridis(len(df['REGION'].tolist()))
p=figure(x_range=df['REGION'],title="Homeless In Ireland 2018", plot_height=400, plot_width=800)
p.vbar(x=df["REGION"], top = df["HOMELESS ADULTS"],width=0.9, color=colours)
show(p)
```

[image: Plot]